# Write to only one column in a listView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have two columns in my listView, lets call them Column1, and Column2.

Is it possible to add a bunch of items to column1 only, and make it so those items only go strictly under column1 and not column2?

When I add items it adds an item to Column1, and then Column2 and I don't want that.

How would I go about doing this?

Here's some of my test code. I made an array with two strings. I want both of  those strings to go under column1 (each in their own row) and not under column2. When I test it, they still go under column1 AND column2 which is what I don't want.

```
string[] h = {"Hi","Hello"};
listViewGoogleInsight.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(h));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
string[] h = {"Hi","Hello"}; 
foreach(string s in h) //this in case when you have more that two strings in you array
   listViewGoogleInsight.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(s));
```

In your code you are passing a string array to the constructor of a `ListViewItem` which is creating one ListViewSubitem of the "Hello". You should add each string separately.

EDIT: After your request to add only to column2 you can do it like this. You must pass empty string to for the first column because you need to make a ListViewItem for the first column and additional ListViewSubitems for every other column.

```
    string[] h = { "Hi", "Hello" };
int count=0;
                foreach (string s in h) //this in case when you have more that two strings in you array
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items[count++];
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(s);
                    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
```

Comment: So lets say I wanted to repeat the process with column2 I would use subview correct?

Comment: How would I do it for column2 only?

Comment: The code to add it to the subitem works, but now there are empty spots. Anyway to loop through it and delete and empty blocks so column1 and column2 can align?

Comment: With the code now in column2 I have a bunch of empty spots. Is there a way I can remove those empty spots and push everything up?

Comment: It depends how you set the ListView.View property. Try to set it to details or some other and see how it changes.

Comment: Here's a pic to show you how my form looks after using the code you provided to write to column2: [link](http://content.screencast.com/users/kytro360/folders/Jing/media/838ca0aa-f132-4cb8-b72c-c863ee3956bb/2012-11-05_2052.png)

As you can see there are a bunch of blank spots, and then the items are added to column2. Is there a way to remove those blank spots so the items below it move up and align themselves with the items in column1?

Comment: I am going to sleep,it's 3 am here. You shold iterate through the listviewitems and only add subitems. I'll post the code tomorow.

Comment: Rest, hopefully you'll have time to help me tomorrow.

Heres the error Im getting after executing your code: Cannot add or insert the item 'pro soccer' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it.


I am running a code previously to add to column1 and then this one for column2.

Comment: Hey I asked on a forum and they provided me with an answer :)